# Want to create a custome type to use in a List<T> from Assembly.LoadFrom()

Tags: c#, .net, list, reflection

The title says it all, but here's some sample code of what it might look like

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(trustMeThePathIsRight);
Type test = a.GetType("Full.Path.Of.Desired.Type");
List<test> blah = new List<test>;
```

but it says that type or namespace could not be found.  Essentially, how do I get to use the type I get from creating the assembly reference?

Comment: Whenever you write "don't know the type" code, you should always think of the *dynamic* keyword.  A `List<dynamic>` would be appropriate here.  Make it better by defining an *interface* in a separate assembly that both you and the plugin know about.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you can't use it like that. Type parameters, when specified at compile time, must be known at compile time. The only alternative is to use reflection:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(trustMeThePathIsRight);
Type test = a.GetType("Full.Path.Of.Desired.Type");
Type listType = typeof(List<>).CreateGenericType(test);
IList blah = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Of course the problem here is that the type is still not known, so you won't get compile-time type checking.